# Read data from wikipedia using API

Tags: matlab, api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

For my project, I am trying to read data from Wikipedia, I am not completely sure, how I can do that.

My main concern is to read, date, location and subject of event.
For a start, I have started reading above mentioned information for 91st academy awards.

I tried using Wikipedia query service, but it didn't helped much.

Then I came across API solution and ran following URL,
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=91st_Academy_Awards

But didn't found the information what I was looking for.

I am trying to read the information marked in red box in below image,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7hFL.png]

Can somebody help me with this and let me know how can I read the above mentioned section.

PS:I am using Matlab for writing my algorithm

Comment: I'm afraid you have to go for the [text API call](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=91st_Academy_Awards), search for the `<table class=\"infobox vevent\" ... >`, and parse all information till the corresponding closing `</table>`.

Comment: Hello HansHirse,

Thank you so much for the help.
I will try to parse it using </table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to read the webpage using [webread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html), and process the data using the functions from the [Text Analytics Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/textanalytics/index.html):

```
% Read HTML data.
raw = webread('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=91st_Academy_Awards');

% Specify sections of interest.
SectionsOfInterest = ["Date","Site","Preshow hosts","Produced by","Directed by"];

% Parse HTML data.
myTree = htmlTree(raw.parse.text.x_);

% Find table element.
tableElements = findElement(myTree,'Table');
tableOfInterest = tableElements(1);

% Find header cell elements.
thElements = findElement(tableOfInterest,"th");
% Find cell elements.
tdElements = findElement(tableOfInterest,"td");

% Extract text.
thHTML = thElements.extractHTMLText;
tdHTML = tdElements.extractHTMLText;

for section = 1:numel(SectionsOfInterest)

   sectionName = SectionsOfInterest(section);
   sectIndex = strcmp(sectionName,thHTML);

   % Remove spaces if present from section name.
   sectionName = strrep(sectionName,' ','');

   % Clean up data.
   sectData = regexprep(tdHTML(sectIndex),'\n+','.');

   % Create structure.
   s.(sectionName) = sectData;
end
```

Visualising the output structure:

```
>> s
s = 

struct with fields:

        Date: "February 24, 2019"
        Site: "Dolby Theatre.Hollywood, Los Angeles, California, U.S."
Preshowhosts: "Ashley Graham.Maria Menounos.Elaine Welteroth.Billy Porter.Ryan Seacrest. "
  Producedby: "Donna Gigliotti.Glenn Weiss"
  Directedby: "Glenn Weiss"
```

Comment: Hello UnbearableLightness,

Thank you so much for the help and detail information.
above mentioned functions are not available in my Matlab, probably text analytics toolbox is not installed.

Is there any other way without using the toolbox?

Comment: thank you so much for the help, without using toolbox, I managed to parsed the required information